# Are there any good iPhone camera apps that properly rotate photos?

Tags: iphone, photos, camera

I have an iPhone 4s. I'm happy with the default Camera app, however every time I import photos to Picasa or email them or use them on a website or something they're improperly rotated. This is because the iPhone doesn't rotate the photo, it only saves rotation in metadata, and it is extremely annoying. So are there any good camera apps that actually rotate the photo (not just metadata) *and* saves photos to Photo-stream and saves photos and videos to the camera roll/Photos app? I'd even pay $1 or $2 if need be, but it has to save pictures to the same place that the default app does and has to rotate properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any I think ProCam might do this by default. There's no specific settings for where to do the rotation, but if I don't remember wrong it actually rotates the image. I'm not sure if the app is free or costs anything since I got it thru appoftheday for free.

Have a try. If you want I can check it out further so you don't need to purchase the app?

**Edit:**

Sorry to dissapoint you. Neither of the apps: ProCam, Awesomemize or Awesome Camera does this. I tested all of them by taking a photo upside down and mailing it to myself. The image arriving on my computer was also upside down.

If youre into code you should have a look at whats going wrong and how to fix it: 
http://pleaselistencarefully.com/Why-photo-rotation-is-broken-on-the-iphone-4-and-how-to-fix-it-using-paperclip-on-heroku

Comment: Yes, if you could confirm that before I purchase it, that would be awesome. If it rotates properly, saves to camera roll (and consequently to photo stream indirectly as well), then ProCam would be a dream come true!

Comment: Okay, I guess the answer is there is no good answer and we have to wait for Apple to see the light. I guess keep reporting bugs about it?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I just rotated photos in three apps: Snapseed, FX Photo Studio and Instagram and then saved them via iTunes to my Mac, as well as emailed and opened from the Mac. The rotation was there:)

Answer (score 0):

**Camera Awesome** may achieve this:

http://www.awesomize.com/

Comment: I remember trying Camera Awesome a while back and think it had the same rotation problems and didn't save photos to the camera roll (though I may be mistaken, it was a few months back).

Comment: @AL I havent tried it, so i wouldnt know it has been rectified since

Answer (score 0):

Tony Thomas's [Camcorder++](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/camcorder++-real-time-video/id671882017?mt=8) does the rotation properly for stills and videos.

Answer (score -2):

Photo Rotate, or Image Straightener.